# NOT NULL constraint failed: music_song.album_id

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.11.6 and python 3.6.2

I'm new to django and there is no one to help me where i live so you guys are all my hope

in my django application in the add song section i faced an error

error message =

> IntegrityError at /music/album/5/AddSong/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   music_song.album_id

here is my views file:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

from .models import Album, Song
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'album'


class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']


class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['song_title', 'file_type']



class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']


class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:index')


class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form.html'


    #display a blank form
    def get(self,request):

        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name, {"form": form})


    #procces form data
    def post(self,request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            #cleaned (normalized)  data

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()


            #returns User objects if credentials are correct

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:

                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('music:index')

        return render(request,self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

and here is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # song_file = models.FileField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.album.id})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

    # /music/album/54

    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # music/album/add
    url(r'album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),



    # music/album/3/AddSong
    url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/AddSong/$', views.SongCreate.as_view(), name='song-add'),

    # music/album/2/update/
    url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/AlbumUpdate/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='album-update'),


    # music/album/2/delete/
    url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/AlbumDelete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),

]
```

For creating forms I used Django built-in forms,I had to create one for adding albums and another for adding the album's songs

Here is my album_form.html screenshot
[image]
and here is my form-template.html screenshot:
[image]
and here is my song_form.html screenshot
[image]

Comment: `class Song(models.Model):` - I see no mention of album_id, which translates into inserting NULL into album_id, which triggers the contraint on the Database level. Add album_id to the class, or just modify album to album_id, if that was the original intention.

Comment: @g00dy album_id is the foreignkey. Django adds _id

Comment: Pass the 'Album' in the fields of SongCreateView.

Comment: Please post code as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `form_valid` method, you should fetch the album pk from the url kwargs and set the album on the form instance.

```
from. django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['song_title', 'file_type']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.album = album
        return super(SongCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: it worked fine
 
but i didn't understand the logic behind it

could you be more specific?

thanks

Comment: Your `Song` model has an `album` field. You don't include that field in your form, so you have to set the value in the view otherwise you get the not null constraint error message. In the code above, we fetch the primary key from the url, then use it to set the album. Overriding `form_valid` is similar to [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) in the docs.

Comment: thank you so much man you're the best man

is there a way that i can be in contact with you directly 

there is nobody arund me that undrestands django and sometimes I really get stucked for days to solve a silly problem

Comment: Happy to help, but I can't do one-to-one help I'm afraid. Please ask another question if you get stuck again.